# What did the word "arcade" mean before video games?

Tags: meaning, grammar, history, historical-change

I was browsing a document on the history of Leicestershire in the UK. About halfway down the page, in the "Leicester in the 19th Century" section, it said:

> Silver Arcade was built in 1899.

What does the word Arcade refer to here?

Comment: i like this question. no it's not a simple dictionary look up. in fact who would expect that dictionary definition is the ancient meaning instead of contemporary meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick dictionary search shows the following:

[Arcade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arcade):

> 1:  a long arched building or gallery
>   2
>   :  an arched covered passageway or avenue (as between shops)
>   3
>   :  a series of arches with their columns or piers
>   4
>   :  an amusement center having coin-operated games

The video game usage comes from the notion of a covered passageway or gallery.  These galleries were often filled with mechanical, coin-operated games.  ([Penny arcades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusement_arcade#Penny_arcade), etc.)  Video games were the descendants of these forms of entertainment, so the name was extended to them.